# MongoDB + Morphia - full text search using AND instead of OR

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I've setup full text search and MongoDB and it's working quite well (Mongo 2.6.5).

However it does an OR instead of and AND.

1) Is it possible to make the query an AND query, while still getting all the benefits of full text search (stemming etc.)

2) And if so, is it possible to add this option via the Morphia wrapper library

**EDIT**

I see that the full text search includes a 'score' for each document returned. Is it possible to only return docs with a certain score or above. Is there some score that would represent a 'fuzzy' and query. That is usually all tokens are in the document but not absolutely always. If so this would solve the problem as well.

Naturally if possible to do this via Morphia that would be super helpful. But I can use the native java driver as well.

Any pointers in the correct direction, much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Code looks like this, I'm using Morphia 1.0.1:

```
Datastore ds = Dao.instance().getDatabase();
Query<Product> q = ds.createQuery(Product.class).search("grey vests");
List<Product> prods = q.asList();
```

Printing the query gives:

```
{ "$text" : { "$search" : "grey vests"}}
```

**Note:** I am able to do take an intersection of multiple result sets to create an AND query. However this is very slow since something like "grey" will return a massive result set and be slow at feeding the results back.

**EDIT**

I've tried to chain the `search()` calls and add a single 'token' to each call. But I am getting a run time error. Code becomes:

```
q.search("grey").search("vests");
```

The query I get is (which seems like it's doing the right thing) ...

```
{ "$and" : [ { "$text" : { "$search" : "grey"}} , { "$text" : { "$search" : "vests"}}]}
```

The error is:

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 17287 and error message 'Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Too many text expressions' on server ...
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getQueryFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:93)
```

Comment: The default is to and terms together unless in a $and or $or.  What does your code look like?  also, if you print out the query.toString() and post that it could be helpful.

Comment: Point being, don't write a query like this ( JSON syntax fof visual ) : `{ "$and": [{ "$text": { "$search": "term" },{ "someField": "value }] }` but write it like this instead: `{ "$text": { "$search": "term" }, "someField": "value" }`. They are both intrinsically the same thing, with the exception that the `$and` form is not allowed with `$text` as that operator "must" be specified as a "top level" operator in the query. So it is all about the query construction you use.

Comment: Thanks for the help, apologies for the delayed response. If I can figure this out, will be a big win.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The docs seem to say that `"A query can specify, at most, one $text expression."` Are they wrong? Also, you should add that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @BT That is exactly what I said. I think you misread it.

Comment: @BlakesSeven But it looks like you said that `{ "$text": { "$search": "term" }, "someField": "value" }` would work, whereas the docs say that wouldn't work because it has two text expressions. Which am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @BT It's a typo. The "body" of what I I said was *"the $and form is not allowed with $text as that operator "must" be specified as a "top level" operator in the query"*. Also note the question is edited "after" the statement was made to show "two" `$text` operations and not just `$text` search condition and a "regular" query condition. You cannot have any more than **one** `$text` or "geospatial" special index query operations in the same query.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Well make it an answer! : )